# Voice activated / HF inputs: how can you escape special function phrases?

Tags: voice-recognition, hands-free

For example, say I have a sentence that I want to end with a period then have returned to a new line, but the contents of that sentence itself *include* `period` and `new line` as literals.  Is it possible to use voice-only commands to write such a message?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the sentences below. They should have been separated by a new line.

```
The first period is about to start.
He crossed a new line on the sand.
This is the end of a period.
```

In my case, period was handled correctly the majority of the time whether I wanted the word period or a dot for the first sentence. The 3rd sentence was hit and miss. For a sentence that as both the word period and the punctuation mark period, you can make it easy for the phone by saying `full stop` so it can differentiate between the two. But for the third sentence, the differentiation did not work.

To go to a new line, I had to pause 1-2 seconds before saying new line. Only then, was it recognized as starting a new line and not the literal `new line`.

In both cases, while dictating my sentences in one go, the literals were considered. Pausing would insert the punctuation marks. This is not a scientifically proven experiment. You will have to test on your side and reach a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I found saying "new line" is very hit-or-miss[1], but "carriage return" seems to work more consistently. I haven't actually found this documented anywhere. AFAICT the ["Text Editing" section of the online Voice Access commands reference](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6151854#zippy=%2Ctext-editing) makes no mention of punctuation, including "new line" or "carriage return", while the command reference on the phone (via `Voice Access settings` => `Voice Access commands` or saying "what can I say") lists "new line", but not "carriage return"

[1]: Very occasionally it actually inserts a new line, but it seems to far more often get mis-recognized and inserted as "New life" "Do line" etc. (seems to be mis-recognized far more often than any other phrase for some reason. Maybe because I'm often saying it in isolation, out of the context of a full sentence?)